# EF core: cannot insert object with foreign key using ID properties (only navigation properties work)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core to create my (code first) database model.
In the model I have these classes:

```
[Table("groups")]
public class Group {
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Membership> Members { get; set; }
}

[Table("identities")]
public class Identity {
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Membership> MemberOf { get; set; }
}

[Table("memberships")]
public partial class Membership {
    [Column("group_id")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    [Column("identity_id")]
    public int IdentityId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Identity Identity{ get; set; }
}
```

`Membership` is a many-to-many relationship between `Group` and `Identity`.
I have configured the relationship using the fluent API like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>();
    entity.HasKey(e => new { 
        e.GroupId, 
        e.IdentityId }
    ).HasName("PK_identity_memberships");
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Group)
        .WithMany(p => p.Members)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.GroupId)
        .HasConstraintName("memberships_group_id_fkey");
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Identity)
        .WithMany(p => p.MemberOf)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdentityId)
        .HasConstraintName("memberships_identity_id_fkey");
}
```

My problem is that if I try to insert a `Membership` in the DB setting `GroupId` and `IdentityId` with valid values, I get this error:

Npgsql.PostgresException: 23503: insert or update on table "memberships" violates foreign key constraint "memberships_group_id_fkey"

To insert a `Membership` object, I need to set the `Group` and `Identity` navigation properties, and then everything works fine.

Is there a way to insert new objects without using the navigation properties?

Comment: When you set FKs, are navigation properties `null` or they hold some objects? Also what EF Core version are you on?

Comment: Yes, navigation properties are `null`. I'm using EF core 1.1.2.

Comment: Can't reproduce with SqlServer. Just for clarity, you do something like `context.Add(new Membership { GroupId = some_existing_group_id, IdentityId = some_existing_identity_id });`, i.e. the FKs are of existing groups/identity, not new ones with temporary PKs?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing, the group and identity id are of objects that already exist in the DB. If I add the object in the DB table directly, it works.

Comment: Can't reproduce with SqlServer. Might be Npgsql provider specific (although does not make any sense). Good luck.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for checking this out :)

Comment: Could you please try `public int? GroupId { get; set; }` in `Membership` class?

Comment: @IvanStoev, out of curiosity, I've found the problem (see answer below). It was due to me using `0`s as IDs :(

Comment: Aha, I think this will explode for SqlServer as well. 0 (CLR default value) is treated as not specified, hence auto generated. See [Value generated on add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add)

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found the problem. To reproduce (at least with NpgSql):

```
using (var db = new TestContext()) {

    // This works:
    db.Groups.Add(new Group {
        Id = 42,
    });
    db.Identities.Add(new Identity {
        Id = 666,
    });
    db.SaveChanges();

    db.Memberships.Add(new Membership { 
        GroupId = 42,
        IdentityId = 666
    });
    db.SaveChanges();

    // this explodes...
    db.Groups.Add(new Group {
        Id = 0,
    });
    db.Identities.Add(new Identity {
        Id = 0,
    });
    db.SaveChanges();

    db.Memberships.Add(new Membership { 
        GroupId = 0,
        IdentityId = 0
    });
    db.SaveChanges(); // exception here!

}
```

So, the problem was that I was using `0` as an ID for the objects I had created.
Using a non-zero integer, even negative, seems to work instead.
This might be a bug in NpgSql, I suppose, since 0 seems to be a valid value for an ID (since I can insert records manually in the DB).